# Docker-compose : understanding linking environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm now using `docker-compose` for all of my projects. Very convenient. Much more comfortable than manual linking through several `docker` commands.

There is something that is not clear to me yet though: the logic behind the linking environment variables.

Eg. with this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
mongodb:
  image: mongo
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
web:
  build: .
  command: npm start
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3001:3000"
  links:
    - mongodb
  environment:
    PORT: 3000
    NODE_ENV: 'development'
```

In the node app, I need to retrieve the mongodb url. And if I `console.log(process.env)`, I get so many things that it feels very random (just kept the `docker-compose`-related ones):

```
MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP: 'tcp://172.17.0.2:27017',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT: '27017',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_PROTO: 'tcp',
MONGODB_ENV_MONGO_VERSION: '3.2.6',
MONGODB_1_ENV_GOSU_VERSION: '1.7',
'MYAPP_MONGODB_1_ENV_affinity:container': '=d5c9ebd7766dc954c412accec5ae334bfbe836c0ad0f430929c28d4cda1bcc0e',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_ENV_GPG_KEYS: 'DFFA3DCF326E302C4787673A01C4E7FAAAB2461C \t42F3E95A2C4F08279C4960ADD68FA50FEA312927',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_PORT_27017_TCP: 'tcp://172.17.0.2:27017',
MONGODB_1_PORT: 'tcp://172.17.0.2:27017',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_ENV_MONGO_VERSION: '3.2.6',
MONGODB_1_ENV_MONGO_MAJOR: '3.2',
MONGODB_ENV_GOSU_VERSION: '1.7',
MONGODB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR: '172.17.0.2',
MONGODB_1_NAME: '/myapp_web_1/mongodb_1',
MONGODB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT: '27017',
MONGODB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_PROTO: 'tcp',
'MONGODB_1_ENV_affinity:container': '=d5c9ebd7766dc954c412accec5ae334bfbe836c0ad0f430929c28d4cda1bcc0e',
MONGODB_PORT: 'tcp://172.17.0.2:27017',
MONGODB_1_ENV_GPG_KEYS: 'DFFA3DCF326E302C4787673A01C4E7FAAAB2461C \t42F3E95A2C4F08279C4960ADD68FA50FEA312927',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_ENV_GOSU_VERSION: '1.7',
MONGODB_ENV_MONGO_MAJOR: '3.2',
MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR: '172.17.0.2',
MONGODB_NAME: '/myapp_web_1/mongodb',
MONGODB_1_PORT_27017_TCP: 'tcp://172.17.0.2:27017',
MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT: '27017',
MONGODB_1_ENV_MONGO_VERSION: '3.2.6',
MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP_PROTO: 'tcp',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_PORT: 'tcp://172.17.0.2:27017',
'MONGODB_ENV_affinity:container': '=d5c9ebd7766dc954c412accec5ae334bfbe836c0ad0f430929c28d4cda1bcc0e',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_ENV_MONGO_MAJOR: '3.2',
MONGODB_ENV_GPG_KEYS: 'DFFA3DCF326E302C4787673A01C4E7FAAAB2461C \t42F3E95A2C4F08279C4960ADD68FA50FEA312927',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR: '172.17.0.2',
MYAPP_MONGODB_1_NAME: '/myapp_web_1/novatube_mongodb_1',
```

Don't know what to pick, and why so many entries? Is it better to use the general ones, or the `MYAPP`-prefixed one? Where does the `MYAPP` name comes from? Folder name?

Could someone clarify this?

Wouldn't it be easier to let the user define the ones he needs in the `docker-compose.yml` file with a custom mapping? Like:

```
  links:
    - mongodb:
      - MONGOIP: IP
      - MONGOPORT : PORT
```

What I'm saying *might* not have sense though. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are a legacy way of defining links between containers. If you are using a newer version of compose, you don't need the `links` declaration at all. Trying to connect to `mongodb` from your app container will work fine by just using the name of the service (`mongodb`) as a hostname, without any links defined in the compose file (instead using docker's builtin DNS resolution, check /etc/hosts, nothing in there either!)

In answer to your question about why the prefix with `MYAPP`, you're right. Compose prefixes the service name with the name of the folder (or 'project', in compose nomenclature). It does the same thing when creating custom networks and volumes.

Comment: Thanks for all those clarifications. If I understand correctly, it means in the `MYAPP` container, I'll call the mongo one with something like `mongo.connect('http://mongodb')`?

Comment: That sounds GREAT! :-)